# how to make hotspot on the raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, hotspot

I have successfully to configured my raspberry pi as hotspot using **hostapd and udhcpd** according to [this](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot)

tutorial.

However, I still have some question.

- When I issue `ifconfig` command I see wlan0 assigned `169.254.114.8` as IP address. Where does that come from? can we change it ?
- obtaining the `DHCP` address takes around 20 second. Is it possible to make it shorter?

Here is the output of `ifconfig`

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:32:03:7f  
      inet addr:169.254.114.8  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::207c:acf3:a77a:e12/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9959 errors:0 dropped:20 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:757509 (739.7 KiB)  TX bytes:420952 (411.0 KiB)
```

and here is the route -n command output:

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0`

Comment: `169.254.114.8` is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) i.e. no address has been "assigned"

Comment: You are right I didn't assign an address to `wlan0`